# Is there anything known about $\sup_{s\leq t} \vert B_s \vert - f(s)$, where $B$ is a Brownian motion and $f$ measurable.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

If we consider the process $$ Y^f_t := \sup_{s\leq t} \vert B_s \vert - f(s)$$
is there anything known about the distribution or at least the probability $\Bbb P (Y^f_t \leq 0 )$ ?

Of particular interest would be continuous functions $f$, and functions of the form $f_1 \equiv c$, where $ c>0 $ or $f_2 = c + \delta\cdot \Bbb 1_{[u,s)}$ where $s>u > 0 $.

For example one could ask if $\Bbb P (Y_t^{f_1} \leq 0) < \Bbb P (Y_t^{f_2} \leq 0)$, which is very reasonable at first sight but I see no easy way to prove it.

Comment: To prove your inequality -- the part that requires work is $<$, correct? Have you tried using Levy's forgery theorem? I think it will let you guarantee a positive probability event where $Y_t^{f_1} > 0 $ while $Y_t^{f_2} < 0$. Since $Y_t^{f_1} \geq Y_t^{f_2}$ a.s. (provided you use the same Brownian motion for both), that should be enough to conclude. (I got confused about the direction of the inequalities a few times though.)

Comment: Correct. Yes, that would really help I guess. Since the Brownian motion has positive probability to stay around $c+\delta $ while being greater than $c$ this should give the right answer. When I have the time I will fit in the technical details. I remember this theorem from an exercise, I had to solve a few years ago. Didn't know it has a name.

Comment: Btw: To ask for the probabilities $\mathbb P (Y_t^f \leq 0)$, $t>0$, corresponds to the so-called first-passage time problem of Brownian motion.